# How to add GUI installed programs

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I've recently started using Chocolatey to install new programs on my computer and to then subsequently upgrade them. However, there are many programs that I have already installed which appear when I run

```
choco search ProgramName
```

but do not appear when I run

```
choco list --local-only
```

because I did not install them with Chocolatey. For some of these programs at least, I'd like to start using Chocolatey to upgrade them to the newest version. The simplest solution would be to simply uninstall the program and then reinstall it using Chocolatey, but this might result in me losing some of my saved preferences (or, for larger programs, this is simply a waste of bandwidth and time). Is there a way for me to add the program to Chocolatey without uninstalling it? If so, is there a way to search for all installed programs on my computer that Chocolatey could maintain for me (rather than adding them one at a time)?

Comment: I wondered this myself, especially when the docs seemed to say that (most?) Chocolatey packages just automate the regular install process. I decided to throw caution to the wind and simply have Chocolatey install something over the top of an existing install (in this case `vlc`). And I can report that this seems to have worked; I don't have two copies installed, and existing settings were preserved. But it does still waste bandwidth and time.

Comment: Further information: *some* Chocolatey packages (I note that Chrome is one of them) explicitly check whether the up-to-date version is already installed, and don't re-download it if it is... and then they *do* add it to Chocolatey's installed list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
choco list --local-only --includeprograms
```

> -i, --includeprograms, --include-programs
>
> IncludePrograms - Used in conjunction with LocalOnly, filters out apps chocolatey has listed as packages and includes those in the list.
>
> Defaults to false.

It lists the programs managed by chocolatey plus those it does not manage.

Comment: For future readers: this answer, in conjunction with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290384/11659881), tells me that while I have the ability to *list* the applications not managed with Chocolatey, I would need a licensed version of Chocolatey to have Chocolatey manage them.